# Prove $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable.

**My attempt:**
We know $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set (trivial)

Moreover, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a countable set because we can construct a bijective function in $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that

I have stuck because i want prove $\mathbb{Z^n}$ is countable.

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759727/how-can-i-prove-that-these-sets-are-countable-infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You know $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, then $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable you can prove that exists a bijective function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and then use induction for prove for $\mathbb{Z}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer very clear.